# What is an evaluation operator and what is its use?

Tags: numerical-methods, definition

In a lecture about numerical mathematics, mostly about ODEs, we were given the following definition:

> The two-parametric family $\mathbf \Phi^{s,t}$ of maps $\mathbf \Phi^{s,t}: D \mapsto D$ is called *evaluation operator* of the differential equation $\mathbf{\dot{y}} = \mathbf f(t,\mathbf y)$, if $t \in J(s,\mathbf z) \mapsto \mathbf \Phi^{s,t} \mathbf z$ is a solution of the initial value problem $\mathbf{\dot{y}} =f(t,\mathbf y), \mathbf y(s) = \mathbf z$ for all $(s,\mathbf z) \in \Omega$.

This definition is followed by an example: For $f(t,y) = - \lambda y$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we have the evaluation operator $\mathbf \Phi^t: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \mathbf \Phi^t(y_0) = e^{-\lambda t} y_0$. This just seems to be the solution of the initial value problem.

I tried googling and didn't find any other website even coming up with an expression like this. In some of our exercises, we are supposed to prove statements involving this evaluation operator and I honestly have no idea how to approach them even after having read the standard solution. Could anybody explain what this evaluation operator actually does and what it is used for? If possible, could anyone provide a non-trivial example? Because the example given in our lecture really doesn't help me understand it at all... Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's exactly what $\Phi^t$ is by the way, it's a solution of an initial value problem.  Note that $s$ in your example is just $0$ since $y(0) = y_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^{(1)} = f(t,y)$ represents a time-dependent differential equation for a point $y(t) \in D$ which is a function of the variable $t$. The variable $s$ tells us what time value $t$ to start evaluating from and $z$ is the initial value in $D$, ie) $y(s) = z$.

$J(s,z)$ is just an interval of time for which $y$ will be defined because we often can't extend solutions of differential equations out to all time values.

So suppose I gave you $s$ and $z$.  This means I set $y(s) = z$.  I then know locally, $$y(s + \delta t) \approx y(s) + y'(t) \delta t = z +  f(t,y) \delta t$$

This means that $\Phi^{s, s + \delta t} z \approx z + f(t,y) \delta t$

I hope this gives you a feel for how it all works.  I can elaborate as much as you need otherwise.